# (woocommerce) different shipping method per product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im working with woocommerce but i can not finde the solution for different shipping per product. I have two product.

First one: You can pick up at the store OR express shipping 
Second one: You only can pick up at store we can not ship it.

Is there any way to set this ?

Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes per product shipping is possible in woocommerce, have you read [this](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/per-product-shipping/)?
There are also multiple Wordpress plugins to achieve this if the default behaviour doesn't fit your needs. I'm not gonna link them though, it's easeri for you to choose if you Google them :)